# How to delete files from usb drive

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive, iso, delete, fdisk

I have just burned an .iso onto a usb drive, and i suspect something has gone wrong as it won't boot, so i want to wipe it and try again, but it won't let me remove files. When I use fdisk -l I get:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd9dca955

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 233469951 233467904 111.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       233471998 250068991  16596994   7.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       233472000 250068991  16596992   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.3 GiB, 15376000000 bytes, 30031250 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But under /dev/sdb there used to be a devices section like with /dev/sda, I'm assuming its to do with that. How do I get that back?

Comment: What do you mean by " it won't let me remove files." ?

Comment: You need to add a partition table.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat I can view the files in the GUI but i can't remove or edit them. It has become read only.

Comment: There may be a hardware problem or a software problem. See the following link (and links from it), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, This happened hundred times with me. While Burning the iso, it creates the iso size partition in usb and copies the data into that partition and makes it read only.

Follow the GUI procedure ~>

Open **Disks** from dash.

Select the usb drive from sidebar.

[image]

Then click on the three dot on top-right corner and click "Format Disk..." and complete it.

[image]

Then click the on "+" icon, left the all field as default and simply click "create".

[image]

Then click the gear icon and select "Format Partition" and complete the process.

[image]

Remove the USB drive and reinsert.

Comment: rm -f filename  worked on 20.04.